# To subclass or not to subclass : that is the ...?

Tags: ios, xcode, subclass

I am building an app with many views and subviews.
I am trying to figure out how to approach creation of the subclass.

one simple example:
I have a table view with heads view and footer view. (I have much more complex views then this one, but I am trying to explain my point with a simple one).

In the beginning I didn't want to create views subclasses for every view, but I found that my code is getting complex and hard to navigate in.

Then I found my self creating a view for every subview in the main view. The truth is that I like it better cause my code is clearer to me. Th only thing is that I don't know what are to cons and pros of each approach.

How do you decide when to create a custom view or create it's code in the main view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a `UIView` subclass only when there is specific functionality that would be best done in such a class. This might be that the view is a control such as a keyboard to enter a value or a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Otherwise I would generally not subclass `UIView` but just create the view hierarchy in Interface Builder or in code and then use the `UIViewController` subclass to do all the business logic.

Basically, in general with iOS programming, you want to have all the logic of how a "view" (or screen, or whatever you want to call it) in a `UIViewController` subclass. It's hard though to really give good advice without fully understanding your hierarchy.